# C# 4 and CLR Compatibility

Tags: c#, .net, clr

Are all the additions to C# for version 4 (dynamic, code contracts etc) expected to run on the current .NET CLR, or is there a planned .NET upgrade as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C# 4 will require the .NET 4.0 CLR.

Comment: I must admit, I'm not 100% convinced by such a sweeping statement... certainly .NET 4.0 will, but have you tried any of the non-dynamic C# 4.0 things on the VS2010 CTP? Unfortunately I don't have my CTP available at the moment...

Comment: The compiler in VS RC1 compiles "dynamic" and named/optional arguments when I target 3.5.

Answer (score 4):

Well, .NET 4.0 will require CLR 4.0; however, it is a little harder to answer what parts of C# 4.0 will work on .NET 2.0/3.x. We can hope that VS2010 will still be multi-targeting(I  don't have the CTP "on me" so to speak, so I can't check...). But some of the language features don't *seem* hugely tied to the runtime (named parameters, some of the COM changes such as "ref") - so I can't think of a good reason why they wouldn't be available when talking to .NET 2.0/3.x. I haven't checked, though.

However, as with C# 3.0, some of the features *are* tied to the runtime - in particular `dynamic`.

I need to dig out the CTP and have another play, methinks...

Comment: I agree, I can see why dynamic may need a clr update, but code contracts not so much

Comment: Well, code-contracts will require the attributes themselves... and if they are housed in .NET 4.0 (which I suspect they are), you will probably need to target CLR 4.0.

Comment: Although there's a version of code contracts running against .NET 3.5, of course...

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to wait for 4.0 to use Code Contracts as it runs on .NET 3.5, the download link for the academic preview release is [here](http://research.microsoft.com/contracts/#downloads).

Comment: For Academic licensed VS2008 only :(

Comment: Keep the license issues aside, it doesn't need 4.0 runtime to run, that's important and nice.

Comment: Wow, that's awesome. I'm been dying to try it out, but I haven't had time to setup a VS 2010 box.